# Error when installing Chrome Extension: "An error has occurred Could not unzip extension"

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I uploaded a new build of my Chrome Extension. When attempting to test downloading the new build I get the following error message in a modal:

> An error has occurred
>
> Could not unzip extension

Nothing logs in the browser's console, leaving me very little to work with.

Here is an image of the error:

[image]

I've checked my Zip file to ensure the file is not corrupt:

```sh
$ unzip -t ./build.zip
Archive:  build.zip
    testing: assets/img/logo.svg      OK
    testing: assets/img/facebook.svg   OK
    testing: fonts/mr-eaves-modern.woff2   OK
    testing: assets/img/overlay-vignette.png   OK
    testing: manifest.json            OK
    testing: background.js            OK
    testing: main.css                 OK
    testing: main.js                  OK
    testing: options.css              OK
    testing: options.js               OK
    testing: assets/icons/cheveron.svg   OK
    testing: assets/icons/close.svg   OK
    testing: assets/icons/facebook.svg   OK
    testing: assets/icons/fullscreen-enter.svg   OK
    testing: assets/icons/logo.svg    OK
    testing: assets/icons/reddit.svg   OK
    testing: assets/icons/search.svg   OK
    testing: assets/icons/share.svg   OK
    testing: assets/icons/twitter.svg   OK
    testing: assets/img/overlay-vignette.png   OK
    testing: assets/icons/icon16.png   OK
    testing: assets/icons/icon128.png   OK
    testing: assets/icons/embed.svg   OK
    testing: assets/icons/fullscreen-exit.svg   OK
    testing: assets/icons/icon48.png   OK
    testing: assets/img/4674895405383680.jpg   OK
    testing: assets/img/.DS_Store     OK
    testing: assets/img/4565950808457216.jpg   OK
    testing: assets/img/4553408967081984.jpg   OK
    testing: assets/img/5202980357799936.jpg   OK
    testing: assets/img/4861198805762048.jpg   OK
    testing: assets/img/5292847716630528.jpg   OK
    testing: assets/img/5568352688799744.jpg   OK
    testing: assets/img/5553709064912896.jpg   OK
    testing: assets/img/6479776759939072.jpg   OK
    testing: main.html                OK
    testing: options.html             OK
No errors detected in compressed data of build.zip.
```

Has anyone else come across this issue and resolved it?

## Update

I think this has something to do with the settings for the Webpack plugin ([zip-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/zip-webpack-plugin)) I'm using to Zip my project.

I don't have any issues when I manually right click and compress the directory.

Comment: I've seen that happening when you upload a CRX file instead of ZIP.